# Sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$ - $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = a$ if, [...]

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = a$ if, only if, $\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} <x_k, y> = <a, y>$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The first part I did.

$(\Longrightarrow)$Let $a=(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then

$
\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } x_k = a \overbrace{\Rightarrow}^{(1)(2)} 
\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } y_ix_{ki} = y_ia_i$ for $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$.

Then

$
\lim <y, x_k> = 
\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_{ki} = 
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} y_ix_{ki} = 
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n y_ia_i = <y, a>.
$
q.e.d.

(1) I used the Theorem: a sequence $(x_k)$converges to $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if each coordinate of $x_k$ converges for each of the coordinate of $a$.

(2) I used which a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, 
$\lim x_k = a \iff \lim yx_k = ya$ para todo $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

The back I made similarly, but I'm not sure it is correct because 
I'm not sure if it's "back" the statement (2). Especially if $y = 0$.

How do you solve this problem?
What I did is correct?
The fact (2) correct?
The return of the matter is before the analogously using the fact (2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about the linear transformations then you can improve your proof. First note that for each fixed $y\in\mathbb R^n$, the map $\varphi_y:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ given by $\varphi_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ is a linear functional i.e. a linear transformation defined on a finite dimensional vector space and hence $\varphi_y$ is bounded linear map (since any linear map defined on a finite dimensional normed linear space is bounded). Also for a linear map defined on a normed linear space, the notion of continuity and boundedness coincide. Hence the give map $\varphi_y$ is a continuous map. Thus if $x_k\to a$ in $\mathbb R^n$, then $\varphi_y(x_k)\to \varphi_y(a)$ in $\mathbb R$ i.e. $\langle x_k,y\rangle\to\langle a,y\rangle$ for each $y\in \mathbb R^n$.

For the converse, consider the standard ordered basis (which is also actually an orthonormal basis w.r.t. the standard inner product on $\mathbb R ^n$) $B=\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$, where $e_i$ denotes the element of $\mathbb R^n$ with $1$ at the $i^{\text{th}}$-co-ordinate and all other co-ordinates are zero, $1\le i\le n$. Observe that for any $x\in \mathbb R^n$, $\langle x,e_i\rangle$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$-co-ordinate of $x$. Hence by the given condition $\langle x_k, e_i\rangle\to \langle a,e_i\rangle$, for $1\le i\le  n$. Thus for each $i=1,\dotsc,n$, the $i^{\text{th}}$-co-ordinate of $x_k$, say $x_k^{(i)}\to a^{(i)},$ the $i^{\text{th}}$-co-ordinate of $a$. So you can conclude that $x_k\to a$.

Comment: Thank you very much.
And the back?
It is so direct as well?

Just to get my question, if I do the back

$lim <x_k, y> = lim (x_{k1}y_1 + \cdots + x_{kn}y_n) = a_1 + \cdots + a_ny_n = <a, y>$. With this,

$\lim x_{k1} = a_1$, $\lim x_{k2} = a_2$, $\ldots$ $\lim x_{kn} = a_n$, then using (1), 

$ lim_{x_k} = a$.

It's correct?

And how would using the linear functional?

Comment: @ Samuel Francisco See the edit. Actually it is better to use the co-ordinates to conclude the converse.

Comment: @ user149418 Thank you very much!